# Make one div float over another?

Tags: html, css

I have two div elements on a page.
How can I make one div float over another just like a popup? In other words, div2 (the popup) would cover some part of the area of div1 (the parent).

Comment: Mmmm... i guess you want to use a [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` and set the "popup" one to be positioned within the boundaries of the other. The "popup" div should likely also be smaller.

Use `z-index` to stack the "popup" one above the other one (give it a higher value for `z-index`).

If you want to make it look like the inner div is really floating above the other one, create a shadow with something like `border-right:2px solid black` and `border-bottom:2px solid black`.

If you want to make it actually pop up/appear/disappear, you will need to use some script.

Comment: How do I add an "offset" after specifying its position as absolute? It's impossible because it treats the new coordinates as absolute coordinates so it becomes useless. But clearly it should have been possible to specify an offset because even when it's "absolute" it's not displaying at (0, 0)

Comment: I was able to solve my issue using the following:

var l = blah.offset().left;
blah.offset({left: l+10});

Answer (score 12):

I believe setting the `position` to `fixed` will cause it to stay visible even if the user scrolls. You can set the position using "top", "left" and "right" attributes. The CSS I use for a "beta" logo which basically does what you are asking is this:

```
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Then use z-index property of css like this :

```
div1 {
  z-index:1000;
}

 div2 {
 z-index:1001;
}
```

Highest z-index element will be display at top.